# Swift - Singleton Accessor Thread Safety with GCD

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I have read other SO posts on this topic, and have watched WWDC 2016's talk on synchronising subsystems via GCD. See: ~@11.30 mark.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/

After this research, I am still confused as to best practices. I would like guidance on whether the following code is an appropriate way to ensure thread safety for the accessors of a Singleton in Swift.

In the example code below, a singleton (ResourceManager) has two main tasks:

1) given a resourceID and a closure, provide a corresponding Resource through that closure. If the required Resource is already in a private cache, use that, otherwise, the Resource needs to be created asynchronously, and output on the main thread.

2) given a resourceID, tell the caller whether the corresponding Resource is in the private cache.

In the following code, this is implemented through a private, serial GCD queue.

```
struct Resource
{
    ...
}

typealias ResourceID = String

final class ResourceManager
{
    static let shared = ResourceManager()

    fileprivate var _resourcesDict = [ResourceID : Resource]()
    fileprivate let _queue = DispatchQueue(label: "ResourceManager_Queue",
            qos: .userInitiated)

    // Private init to ensure just one instance is created.
    fileprivate init()
    {
    }
}

extension ResourceManager
{
    /// Calls the given closure on the main thread.
    /// If the required Resource is already cached, outputs that Resource.
    /// Otherwise, loads the Resource asynchronously, then caches it
    /// before finally providing it through the closure on the main thread.

    func resource(forResourceID resourceID: ResourceID,
            completionHandler: @escaping (Resource?) -> ())
    {    
        // #1. - SEE BOTTOM OF POST FOR REVISION
        // Resource already in the cache? Use that, job is done.
        if let resource = self._resourcesDict[resourceID] {
            self._queue.sync {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(resource)
                }
            }
            return
        }

        // #2.
        // Resource is not in the cache, so load it asynchronously.
        self._queue.async {
            let maybeResource = Resource(resourceID: resourceID)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let resource = maybeResource {
                    self._resourcesDict[resourceID] = resource
                }
                completionHandler(maybeResource)
            }
        }
    }


    /// Given a resourceID, returns true if the resource is in our cache.

    func resourceIsLoaded(forResourceID resourceID: ResourceID) -> Bool
    {
        // #3.
        // Note: remember we are actually returning the queue.
        return self._queue.sync {
            return self._resourcesDict[resourceID] != nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

Are the mechanisms at #1, #2 and #3 adequate to ensure safety of access? Are there any problems you can see with these approaches?

Is mechanism #2 correct? Or should I be setting the cache using _queue.sync as in the following:

```
self._queue.async {
let maybeResource = Resource(resourceID: resourceID)
self._queue.sync {
    if let resource = maybeResource {
        self._resourcesDict[resourceID] = resource
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completionHandler(maybeResource)
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for any help.

[Edit - Revised `resource(::)` method, as per Mike's suggestions]

```
// Revised at point #1 to do checking within sync

func resource(forResourceID resourceID: ResourceID,
        completionHandler: @escaping (Resource?) -> ())
{    
    // #1. REVISED. Do Resource checking within sync.
    // Resource already in the cache? Use that, job is done.
    self._queue.sync {
        if let resource = self._resourcesDict[resourceID] {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(resource)
            }
        }
        return
    }

    // #2.
    // Resource is not in the cache, so load it asynchronously.
    self._queue.async {
        let maybeResource = Resource(resourceID: resourceID)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let resource = maybeResource {
                self._resourcesDict[resourceID] = resource
            }
            completionHandler(maybeResource)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In objective C we are using @syncronized for thread safety while  self._queue.sync is correct here for thread safety ,

Comment: It would be better if your all code in method in self._queue.sync block , for let other thread to wait untill  your fetching and caching is done

Comment: @MikeAlter Thank you for the help Mike. Could you please elaborate on your last comment... I'm having trouble parsing it due to the comments system. Thanks.

Comment: I am talking about this line ` if let resource=self._resourcesDict[resourceID]` , It should be also in sync block if possible

Comment: @MikeAlter Ah, I see. Thank you. (Sorry for the delay in getting back to you on this, got called away with other jobs.) I've made the change, hopefully, as you suggest. Thanks again.